# How to add already existing ECS Instance to newly created ECS Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-ecs

I'm new to AWS and I'm searching for a way to add already existing ECS instance to newly created ECS Cluster.

Also there is a task that is running on Cluster1, can I copy the task to run on Cluster2, when I try to copy the JSON file I get the following error message:
'Should only contain "family", "containerDefinitions", "volumes", "taskRoleArn", "networkMode"' ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use a task definition in any cluster, so no need to copy the definition.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a running EC2 instance to an ECS cluster? The EC2 instance needs to have docker installed and then you have to docker run the ecs-agent with the environment variable `ECS_CLUSTER` set to the cluster name.

I can recommend the ECS optimized AMI from Amazon. It has docker and ecs-agent installed and is easily configured with the cluster name in the Launch Configurations User Data field.

For question two: when you copy the json you need to remove some attributes from the top of the json. Remove these attributes:

```
"requiresAttributes"
"taskDefinitionArn"
"status"
"revision":
"taskRoleArn"
```